# Quickblox QBChatMessage getDateSent not working

Tags: android, quickblox, android-calendar

As I retrieve a chat history at quickblox, I want to get the datetime each message was sent to show it on my app. The docs for the QBChatMessage states that:

```
public long getDateSent()
Gets the date sent value
```

I suppose this long value refers to the time in milisecs. So I'm setting it to a Calendar, to be able to get its fields:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(messageArray.get(i).getDateSent());
Log.e(TAG, "date sent "+i+" - "+DateHelper.getDateLabel(cal)+" - "+messageArray.get(i).getDateSent());
```

But, although the `getDateSent()` returns different values, the Calendar fields remains the same:

```
04-30 11:51:07.903  20943-20943/com.shoutzapp E/ConversationActivity﹕ date sent 0 - 17/0/1970 - 1430403726
04-30 11:51:07.903  20943-20943/com.shoutzapp E/ConversationActivity﹕ date sent 1 - 17/0/1970 - 1430403749
04-30 11:51:07.904  20943-20943/com.shoutzapp E/ConversationActivity﹕ date sent 2 - 17/0/1970 - 1430403827
04-30 11:51:07.904  20943-20943/com.shoutzapp E/ConversationActivity﹕ date sent 3 - 17/0/1970 - 1430403855
04-30 11:51:07.904  20943-20943/com.shoutzapp E/ConversationActivity﹕ date sent 4 - 17/0/1970 - 1430403912
04-30 11:51:07.905  20943-20943/com.shoutzapp E/ConversationActivity﹕ date sent 5 - 17/0/1970 - 1430403923
```

What am I missing? `getDateSent()` really returns time in millisecs, or am I using Calendar in a wrong way?

Thanks very much for any help on this.

Comment: they look like seconds to me. Try to multiply * 1000

Comment: @Blackbelt you are right! if u post an answer I can accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
04-30 11:51:07.904  20943-20943/com.shoutzapp 
        E/ConversationActivity﹕ date sent 4 - 17/0/1970 - 1430403912
```

According to the log you posted, `getDateSent()` is returning seconds, not milliseconds. Parse `getDateSent() * 1000` to `setTimeInMillis`

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same issue.

My solution is:

```
long milis = 1473232646 * 1000L;
long milis = getDateSent() * 1000L;
```